# Plot a graph from a function in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to insert a graph that is generated from the function.LetControl <-function (coverage). I couldn't show this graphic on my shiny, the others worked. I believe it may be because this function is within another function. Could someone help me solve this problem please.

The executable code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
                                                                                                 + -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
                                                                                                                                                     + -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          + 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

function.clustering<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){
   
    if (Filter1==2){
        Q1<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.25)) 
        Q3<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.75))
        L<-Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)
        S<-Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)
        df_1<-subset(df,Waste>L[1]) 
        df<-subset(df_1,Waste<S[1])
    }
    
    #cluster
    coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
    d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
    fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
    
    
    #Number of clusters
    clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
    nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
    df$cluster <- clusters 
    
    #Localization
    center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
    for(i in 1:k){
        center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                           weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
    coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
    center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 
    
    #Coverage
    coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
    for(i in 1:k){
        aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
        coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
    coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
    colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")
    
    #Sum of Waste from clusters
    sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
    for(i in 1:k){
        sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
    }
    sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
    colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")
    
    #Output table
    data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
    data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Properties)),]
    data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,7,6,2)], toString)
    data_table_1<-kable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1,4,2,3)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
        kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
    
    #Scatter Plot
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
    df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
    colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
    g<-ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) + geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4)
    Centro_View<- g +  geom_text(data=df, mapping=aes(x=eval(Longitude), y=eval(Latitude), label=Waste), size=3, hjust=-0.1)+ geom_point(data=df1, mapping=aes(Longitude, Latitude), color= "green", size=4) + geom_text(data=df1, mapping = aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, label = 1:k), color = "black", size = 4)
    plotGD<-print(Centro_View + ggtitle("Scatter Plot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))

}
    function.LetControl<-function(coverage)
{
  m <- mean(coverage[,1])
  MR <- mean(abs(diff(coverage[,1])))
  d2 <- 1.1284
  LIC <- m - 3*(MR/d2)
  LSC <- m + 3*(MR/d2)
  LetCover<-plot(coverage[,1], type = "b", pch = 16, ylim = c(LIC-0.1*LIC,LSC+0.5*LSC), axes = FALSE) 
  axis(1, at = 1:35)
  axis(2)
  box()
  grid()
  abline(h = MR,
         lwd = 2)
  abline(h = LSC, lwd = 2, col = "red")
  abline(h = LIC, lwd = 2, col = "red")}


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Clustering "),
    
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText(h3("Generation of clustering")),
            
            radioButtons("filter1", h3("Waste Potential"),
                         choices = list("Select all properties" = 1, 
                                        "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" = 2),
                         selected = 1),
            
            radioButtons("filter2", h3("Coverage do cluster"),
                         choices = list("Use default limitations" = 1, 
                                        "Do not limite coverage" = 2
                         ),selected = 1),
        
        tags$hr(),
        
            helpText(h3("Are you satisfied with the solution?")),
            helpText(h4("(1) Yes")),
            helpText(h4("(2) No")),
            helpText(h4("(a) Change the number of clusters")),
          sliderInput("Slider", h3("Number of clusters"),
                        min = 2, max = 34, value = 8),
          helpText(h4("(b) Change the filter options"))
          ),
          
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("tabela"),  
            plotOutput("ScatterPlot"),
            plotOutput("LetCoverage"),
            
        )))

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    f1<-renderText({input$filter1})
    f2<-renderText({input$filter2})


    Modelclustering<-reactive(function.clustering(df,input$Slider,1,1))
    
    output$tabela <- renderUI(HTML(Modelclustering()[["plot_env"]][["data_table_1"]]))
    
    output$ScatterPlot<-renderPlot(Modelclustering()[["plot_env"]][["plotGD"]])
    
    output$LetCoverage <- renderPlot(Modelclustering()[["plot_env"]][["LetCover"]])
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## ERROR TO CHECK

ERROR 1: Argument 1 is not a vector

ERROR 2: non-numeric argument to mathematical

Thank you very much friends!

Comment: You define the function, but you don't call it anywhere. Also, as shown, the function is not within another function.

Comment: Could you help me friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we want to return values from functions, rather than trying to access them with, e.g., `[["plot_env"]][["plotGD"]]`. In `R` to return multiple elements from a function, we must wrap them in a `list()`. For your app, the function `function.clustering()` needs to return 3 elements: the coverage data, the clustering table and the scatter plot. This is handled by:

```
  return(list(
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Plot" = plotGD,
    "Coverage" = coverage
  ))
```

Note that `plotGD` is simply the plot object, not the printed plot. The latter prints the plot to a plotting window/pane, so you have to do the double `[[]][[]]` gymnastics.

Similar for the kable. Return the data.frame (or data.table or matrix), and do the styling inside the server function.

Finally, to use `function.LetCoverage`, we just pass the third element returned by the clustering function. This will make the plot and render it.

HTH,

---

Working app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
                                                                                                                                                 + -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9,-23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     + -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6,-49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          + 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350,350)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))

function.clustering <- function(df, k, Filter1, Filter2) {
  #df is database
  #k is number of clusters
  #Filter1 is equal to 1, if all properties are used
  #Filter1 is equal to 2 is to limit the use of properties that have potential for waste production <L e >S

  if (Filter1 == 2) {
    Q1 <- matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.25))
    Q3 <- matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.75))
    L <- Q1 - 1.5 * (Q3 - Q1)
    S <- Q3 + 1.5 * (Q3 - Q1)
    df_1 <- subset(df, Waste > L[1])
    df <- subset(df_1, Waste < S[1])
  }

  #cluster
  coordinates <- df[c("Latitude", "Longitude")]
  d <- as.dist(distm(coordinates[, 2:1]))
  fit.average <- hclust(d, method = "average")


  #Number of clusters
  clusters <- cutree(fit.average, k)
  nclusters <- matrix(table(clusters))
  df$cluster <- clusters

  #Localization
  center_mass <- matrix(nrow = k, ncol = 2)
  for (i in 1:k) {
    center_mass[i, ] <-
      c(
        weighted.mean(
          subset(df, cluster == i)$Latitude,
          subset(df, cluster == i)$Waste
        ),
        weighted.mean(
          subset(df, cluster == i)$Longitude,
          subset(df, cluster == i)$Waste
        )
      )
  }
  coordinates$cluster <- clusters
  center_mass <- cbind(center_mass, matrix(c(1:k), ncol = 1))

  #Coverage
  coverage <- matrix(nrow = k, ncol = 1)
  for (i in 1:k) {
    aux_dist <-
      distm(rbind(subset(coordinates, cluster == i), center_mass[i, ])[, 2:1])
    coverage[i, ] <- max(aux_dist[nclusters[i, 1] + 1, ])
  }
  coverage <- cbind(coverage, matrix(c(1:k), ncol = 1))
  colnames(coverage) <- c("Coverage_meters", "cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste <- matrix(nrow = k, ncol = 1)
  for (i in 1:k) {
    sum_waste[i, ] <- sum(subset(df, cluster == i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste <- cbind(sum_waste, matrix(c(1:k), ncol = 1))
  colnames(sum_waste) <- c("Potential_Waste_m3", "cluster")

  #Output table
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage, sum_waste))
  data_table <-
    data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Properties)), ]
  data_table_1 <-
    aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3,
              data_table[, c(1, 7, 6, 2)],
              toString)
  #Scatter Plot
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
  df1 <- as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <- c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")
  g <-
    ggplot(data = df,  aes(
      x = Longitude,
      y = Latitude,
      color = factor(clusters)
    )) + geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 4)
  Centro_View <-
    g +  geom_text(
      data = df,
      mapping = aes(
        x = eval(Longitude),
        y = eval(Latitude),
        label = Waste
      ),
      size = 3,
      hjust = -0.1
    ) + geom_point(
      data = df1,
      mapping = aes(Longitude, Latitude),
      color = "green",
      size = 4
    ) + geom_text(
      data = df1,
      mapping = aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, label = 1:k),
      color = "black",
      size = 4
    )

  plotGD <-
    Centro_View + 
    ggtitle("Scatter Plot") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

  return(list(
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Plot" = plotGD,
    "Coverage" = coverage
  ))
}

function.LetControl <- function(coverage) {
  m <- mean(coverage[, 1])
  MR <- mean(abs(diff(coverage[, 1])))
  d2 <- 1.1284
  LIC <- m - 3 * (MR / d2)
  LSC <- m + 3 * (MR / d2)
    plot(
      coverage[, 1],
      type = "b",
      pch = 16,
      ylim = c(LIC - 0.1 * LIC, LSC + 0.5 * LSC),
      axes = FALSE
    )
  axis(1, at = 1:35)
  axis(2)
  box()
  grid()
  abline(h = MR,
         lwd = 2)
  abline(h = LSC, lwd = 2, col = "red")
  abline(h = LIC, lwd = 2, col = "red")
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Clustering "),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(h3("Generation of clustering")),

      radioButtons("filter1", h3("Waste Potential"),
                   choices = list("Select all properties" = 1, 
                                  "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" = 2),
                   selected = 1),

      radioButtons("filter2", h3("Coverage do cluster"),
                   choices = list("Use default limitations" = 1, 
                                  "Do not limite coverage" = 2
                   ),selected = 1),

      tags$hr(),

      helpText(h3("Are you satisfied with the solution?")),
      helpText(h4("(1) Yes")),
      helpText(h4("(2) No")),
      helpText(h4("(a) Change the number of clusters")),
      sliderInput("Slider", h3("Number of clusters"),
                  min = 2, max = 34, value = 8),
      helpText(h4("(b) Change the filter options"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tabela"),  
      plotOutput("ScatterPlot"),
      plotOutput("LetCoverage"),

    )))

server <- function(input, output) {

  f1<-renderText({input$filter1})
  f2<-renderText({input$filter2})


  Modelclustering<-reactive(function.clustering(df,input$Slider,1,1))

  output$tabela <- renderUI({
    data_table_1 <- Modelclustering()[[1]]
    x <- kable(data_table_1[order(data_table_1$cluster), c(1, 4, 2, 3)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE)
    x <- kable_styling(kable_input = x, full_width = FALSE)
    HTML(x)
  })

  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelclustering()[[2]]
  })

  output$LetCoverage <- renderPlot({
    function.LetControl(Modelclustering()[[3]])
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks friend, it worked on this example. However I tested it on another base, it shows two errors (I put it as the image above for you to check. However, when I insert my base through the inputFile, it works. I find it strange to appear these two errors at the beginning. What do you think it is?

Comment: Shiny is trying to make the tables/plots before clustering is done, because you haven't uploaded a dataset yet. This is usually solved by making reactives wait for some input or event. Have a look at the function `shiny::req`

Comment: If it happened in this example, what would you do? Would you use a specific code ??

Comment: `?req` has examples. But in this case, adding `req( Modelclustering() )` inside the `renderUI/renderPlot` expressions (before anything else happens) should be enough. Haven't tested.

Comment: If you just want the first 5 rows, do head(x,5) before rendering the table. If you want to show 5 rows and have all the other times available, look into the DT package that has table pagination.

Comment: Thankssss teofil!!

Comment: Teofil, could you please take a look at either of these two questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569169/plot-scatterplot-on-a-map-in-shiny
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559805/link-selectinput-with-sliderinput-in-shiny

Thank you very much!